# Cucumber & Capybara: Should use rendered.should, page.should or response.should?

Tags: cucumber, response, capybara

Which of the following should I be using for cucumber features that employ capybara?:

```
rendered.should have_selector
page.should have_selector
response.should have_selector
```

I can't seem to get any of them to work - I receive a different error message for each

Answer (score 4):

The correct way is `page.should have_selector`.  Take a look at the [README](https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara), section "Querying", for more documentation.

(There is no method called `rendered` (that I know of), and `response` exists in `Capybara::Driver::RackTest`, but I'm not sure how one might use it -- I've never needed it.)

Comment: Note that `rendered` is available in view specs after a call to `render`.

Answer (score 0):

After some tricky google code searching, the answer seems to be

```
response.should have_selector
```